# getting logging to show for app-engine servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, logging, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an google-endpoint app engine server with one normal servlet class as

```
public class Upload extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Upload.class.getSimpleName());
  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    LOG.warning(“getting in”);
    //….work here
  }
}
```

When I go to app-engine to view the logs, all my endpoint logs are there. But there is no logs for this servlet call. In the `logging.properties` file in WEB-INF, I set level to INFO but that made no difference. Does anyone know how to enable logging for the servlet?

**UPDATE**

Here is my handler:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.package.Upload</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I use the same structure in my other apps and they work fine. I never checked them for logging, though, as I never needed to. The problem here, of course, is that the code has a bug and I am not able to figure it out so I was hoping to use logging to help.

Comment: Assuming that you have set the logging level correctly and uploaded a new version -- are you sure the Servelet and doPost() method are getting invoked ?

Comment: Yep. Your tip got me looking at the easy places for mistakes. And sure enough the dynamic caller was leaving out a slash `/` while generating the url. The server was fine all along.